# Finding overlapping area of vector and raster layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, area

I'm working in QGIS with 3 different layers:

- A raster layer indicating 0 for non-rice and 1 for rice area
- A raster layer indication 0, 1, 2 for different hazard levels
- A vector layer containing the different municipalities. It shows a map with the municipal boundaries and in the attribute table the attribute NAME_2 provides the municipality name.

What I eventually need is for each municipality the total rice area, and the rice area situated in each hazard level. Thus 4 values for all municipalities.

I'm unsure how to do this as there are vector and raster formats (converting them to the same format didn't give the desired result) and as I will need the calculation for each municipality individually.

[image: Image displaying the result of vectorizing the rice field area raster]

Comment: How did vectorizing the rasters not give the desired result? How did you go about it?

Comment: After vectorizing I can't differentiate between rice and non-rice anymore. I'm new to this software but I think it's because there are many different and sometimes super small rice areas. It just shows one big brown area with many little polygons in it, where the rice areas are. I used the polygonize tool

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Have you tried categorizing the polygons?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the result of polygonizing

Comment: Try Zonal statistics

Comment: Zonal statistics seems like the perfect solution, thanks!